# Unable to access Text of Textbox using getText() and getAttribute("value") method using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, gettext

Unable to access Text  of Textbox using getText() and getAttribute("value") method using Selenium WebDriver.
Here i want to get text of First name, When i am using getText() and getAttribute("value") methods, i am getting null result.

Here how webpage and element code looks like
[image]

Here is my code:

```
WebElement T = driver.findElement(By.id("txtFirstName"));
System.out.println("Frist Name is : " + T.getAttribute("value"));
```

&

```
System.out.println("Frist Name is : " + T.getText());
```

Output :

```
Frist Name is :
```

PLZ Help.

Comment: Are you sure, you are locating correct element?? May be there are more element which has same id and you are getting value from wrong element?? Verify it

Comment: Could you share how are you locating the element??

Comment: The `value` attribute is still empty in your HTML inspection window. I don't know Anglular, so I don't know how that might happen, but you should try to fire `document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value` in the console and verify it works there.

Comment: Try using `JavascriptExecutor`..see second edit in the answer...:)

Answer (score 3):

Actually you are calling wrong methods to getting value from text box

- first you are calling `getText()` which would not work on `input` element because `getText()` returns inner text of the element while you are looking for input value
- second you are trying to get value from input using `getAttribute("Value")` which is wrong, it should be `getAttribute("value")` means `v` is in lower case.

So you should try as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.id("textFirstName")).getAttribute("value");
```

**Edited1** :- If unfortunately above does not works, you can try using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :

```
String value = (String)((JavascriptExecutor).executeScript("return arguments[0].value", driver.findElement(By.id("textFirstName")));
```

**Edited2** :-  As I see your element works with `angularjs` so you should try to get value using `angularjs` stufff using `JavascripyExecutor` as below :

```
String value = (String)((JavascriptExecutor).executeScript("return angular.element(arguments[0]).scope().user.st_first_n‌​ame", driver.findElement(By.id("textFirstName")));
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: @Nikunj not able means??is there any exception or anything else??

Comment: @Nikunj And make sure there is only one element by I'd which you want to locate??

Comment: @Nikunj and also as I see in your provided screenshot value Attribute still shows empty, so are you sure there is any value present?? Try once in your browser console by executing `document.getElementById("textFirstName").value` and let me know what is the result??

Comment: @Nikunj and what about browser console result??

Comment: @Nikunj try once using `JavascriptExecutor` , see edited answer and let me know..

Comment: Browser console result is null

Comment: @Nikunj That means clear there is no value present in your input attribute value as it seems in  your screenshot.

Comment: @Nikunj Try once some angular stuff at browser console as `console.log($scope.user.st_first_name)` execute it and let me know the result..:)

Comment: Here is what i get in console
ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

And i also tried javascriptExecutor code you provided but it didn't work, getting blank output

Comment: @Nikunj Are you sure there is value in the input box??

Comment: Yes Value is displaying in the text box same is also editable but not able to read.

Comment: @Nikunj ok try once in browser console as : `var $scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("textFirstName")).scope();console.log($scope.user.st_first_name)` and let me know...:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120301/discussion-between-nikunj-and-saurabh-gaur).

Comment: @Nikunj try with second edited answer to getting value from input box using `JavascriptExecutor`...:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for how to get Text.
(Here  AngularJS is used on to display value for textbox  )

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;     
String addr = js.executeScript("return angular.element(document.getElementById('txtFirstName')).scope().user.st_first_name;").toString();
```

@Saurabh Gaur - Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score -1):

try this
try using single quote

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(); //or wharever broeser you are using
driver.get(url); //url of your webpage
WebElement firstName=driver.findElement(By.ID("txtFirstName");
String fn=firstName.getAttribute('value');
```